# Tab Bar Translucency disabled after dismissing modal view - Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard

I cant figure out why this is happening but when i present a view controller modally, and then dismiss it, the tab bar will forget it's meant to be the black translucent style and revert to whatever solid background colour is set in the storyboard.

Any ideas? I've searched this site and tried different solutions (settings translucency to false, then true) but none have worked.

This is my storyboard set up

```
Tab Bar Controller > Navigation Controller > Table View Controller > Navigation Controller > (Modal) > Table View Controller
```

After dismissing the table view controller, the tab bar will stop being translucent.

I've tried

```
self.tabbar.translucent = false
```

then `true`, in the `viewDidAppear` of the tab bar controller but this doesn't help.

Comment: Please present what you tried, your code.

Comment: I've added some more.